# PHP Form to assign/edit categories

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have my MySQL tables laid out as follows.

```
Products
Categories
Category_map
```

Products can be part of multiple categories so the category_map table could look like this

My form before looked like this(when I had single category

```
<select name=category>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

Then I could insert to MySQL by using MySQLiConnect and using SQL command Insert Category into products where product = product id.

This works fine, but as above with my new table structure I need to be able to add it to multiple categories.

To collect the data in my HTML i can do the following.

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="3">3
</form>
```

I will then get TRUE/FALSE back from each input but how do I handle this in PHP to put into SQL?

I want it to allow multiple entries so IF option 1 and 2 TRUE and 3 False and the current product was product ID 9(let say)

It would add two entries to the category map table as follows...

```
productid       categoryid
    9               1
    9               2
```

I need a form (I presume best way for multiple choice is checkboxes)
So i have the checkboxes for each category but what is the easiest way to add this data on post to the DB (this is admin panel side so doesn't require 'protection')

I could write a if checkbox is false do nothing, if true then insert XYZ to database but this seems pretty cumbersome and I am convinced a better way is available.

Please someone point me in the right direction.

---

Have now sorted this - the main bulk of the code I used was the bits I found here http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

Comment: Hoping this now is edited to fit the rules - i hope! :)

Comment: There really is no magic here.  You have already identified what you need to do.  If certain categories are checked, you simply need to insert applicable records in your DB table. How you handle your unchecked boxes is certainly up to you.  I would think your form might have all categories listed and that you would want to treat a `false` as cause for deletion, otherwise you would need to have some separate means to delete items from categories.

Comment: I have now resolved it after lots of Googling came across this which was very useful. http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

Comment: You may consider adding an answer to your question below, as this could help future people who may find this question.